# Rewriting python script to work with python3

Tags: python, api

I have the following piece of code that I need help rewriting it to work with python3

```
from urllib2 import Request, urlopen

headers = {'Authorization': '< Enter your Basic Authorization string here >'}
request = Request('https://ssapi.shipstation.com/orders/orderId', headers=headers)
request.get_method = lambda: 'DELETE'

response_body = urlopen(request).read()
print response_body
```

Comment: You need to fix your code formatting in your post. Also, `urllib2` was split into `urllib.request` & `urllib.parse`.

Comment: What is your question? This isn't a code-writing service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the imports

```
try:
    from urllib2 import Request, urlopen
except ImportError:
    # python3
    from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
```

Also change the `print`

```
print(response_body)
```

Your code is now cross-compatible and should run on both Python 2 and Python 3.